# How to validate headers and body in Gin-Gonic?

Tags: http, validation, go, go-gin

I have a Gin program. When a request comes, I want all of the fields of the variable `data` (type `ProductCreate`) to have values: `UserId` (from headers) and `Name`, `Price` (from JSON body). I used the below code and it works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type ProductCreate struct {
    UserId int    `header:"user-id"`
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Price  int    `json:"price"`
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.POST("/product", func(c *gin.Context) {
        var data ProductCreate

        // bind the headers to data
        if err := c.ShouldBindHeader(&data); err != nil {
            c.JSON(400, err.Error())
            return
        }

        // bind the body to data
        if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&data); err != nil {
            c.JSON(400, err.Error())
            return
        }

        c.JSON(200, data)
    })

    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

After that, I wanted to make sure that fields must be provided so I edited the `ProductCreate` struct like this:

```
type ProductCreate struct {
    UserId int    `header:"user-id" binding:"required"`
    Name   string `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Price  int    `json:"price" binding:"required"`
}
```

Then it raised an unexpected error when I tested it again:

`Key: 'ProductCreate.Name' Error:Field validation for 'Name' failed on the 'required' tag\nKey: 'ProductCreate.Price' Error:Field validation for 'Price' failed on the 'required' tag`

I realized the error happened at this:

```
// bind the headers to data
if err := c.ShouldBindHeader(&data); err != nil {
   c.JSON(400, err.Error())
   return
}
```

Is there any solution to resolve my problem?

Comment: You can split the structure `ProductCreate`, one gets `UserId` use `ShouldBindHeader` to validate, other gets `Name` and `Price` use `ShouldBindJSON` to validate. Then combine them after validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/product' \
--header 'user-id: 20' \
--data-raw '{
    "name": "sr"   
}'
```

I tried your code and it works perfectly.

```
{
    "UserId": 20,
    "name": "sr",
    "price": 0
}
```

Gin version:    github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.1 // indirect

Soln:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

type ProductCreate struct {
    Name  *string `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Price *int    `json:"price" binding:"required"`
}

type Header struct {
    UserId *int `header:"user-id" binding:"required"`
}

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.POST("/product", func(c *gin.Context) {
        data := &ProductCreate{}
        header := &Header{}

        // bind the headers to data
        if err := c.ShouldBindHeader(header); err != nil {
            c.JSON(400, err.Error())
            return
        }

        // bind the body to data
        if err := c.ShouldBindJSON(data); err != nil {
            c.JSON(400, err.Error())
            return
        }

        c.JSON(200, data)
    })

    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

Comment: It can't. Please read again my question. There is a part I have edited ProductCreate struct (added binding:"required"`).

Comment: @BenAlpha as so mentioned, I have split the header and body. This should work

Comment: Your solution is one of the solutions I considered.
Actually, I have tried to find out a more concise and elegant solution that I think Gin has supported.
Anyway, thanks for the effort.